# Counterexample for Fubini's theorem in a specific situation

Tags: real-analysis

> Give an example for a function $f\in \mathcal L^1(\mathbb R,m)$ where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$, for which $$x\mapsto f(x)f(x+y)$$ is not in $\mathcal L^1(\mathbb R)$ for at least one $y\in\mathbb R$.

---

We know that by Fubini's theorem $f(x)f(x+y)\in\mathcal L^1(\mathbb R^2,m^2)$, and we also know that Fubini's theorem only guarantees that $x\mapsto f(x)f(x+y)$ is in $\mathcal L^1(\mathbb R)$ only for almost every $y\in\mathbb R$ not all over $\mathbb R.$ But can I construct such a specific example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ but not in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ for example
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 &\text{ if }x=0\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt x} &\text{ if }0<|x|\leq 1\\
0 &\text{ if }|x|>1
\end{cases}
$$

then take $y=0$ and $f(x)f(x)=f^2(x)$ is not $L^1(\mathbb R)$

Comment: Thank you! By the way, could you explain why is it so counter-intuitive that we can have some zero-measure sets on which the integral is not integrable but over the product space it's fine?

Comment: Over a zero-measure set can happens anything, a function can also be non defined over a set with zero measure.